# Using custom HTML labels with str_wrap with shiny and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-plotly

I have a shiny which has tooltips which show the full text of a long string. I am able to show all this text in a manageable way using `str_wrap` function in the text argument field for the tooltip.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(stringi)

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model")
dat[["lorem"]] <- rep(stri_rand_lipsum(n_paragraphs = 1), 32)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                 text = str_wrap(lorem, width = 80))) +
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, I would like to also include some other labels, for instance `model` and `mpg`, with some custom styling (i.e. bolding the column titles), along the lines of:

[image]

Cany anyone provide a solution of how to do this - I know how to do it w/o the `str_wrap` function, but can't figure out how to accomplish this w/ it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(stringi)

dat <- mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model")
dat[["lorem"]] <- rep(stri_rand_lipsum(n_paragraphs = 1), 32)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    p1 <- dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                 text = paste0("<b>Model:</b> ", model, "<br>",
                               "<b>MPG:</b> ", mpg, "<br>",
                               str_wrap(paste0("<b>Text:</b> ", lorem), width = 80)
                               ))) +
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]